# Creating a loop for transposing rows to a single column in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to transform a data set with 6 columns into a new data set with a single column. I was trying to implement a loop where R reads each row and pastes it as a column, the next row is pasted below the first column and so on, until I have a single final column.
Here's an example of what I intend to do:

```
row1 <- xlsx_in[1,]
```

> C1        C2        C3        C4        C5       C6
>                                 
>   1 0.0293109 0.0303286 0.0321606 0.0327712 0.0333818 0.034196

```
col1 <- as.data.frame(t(row1))
```

> V1
>   C1 0.0293109
>   C2 0.0303286
>   C3 0.0321606
>   C4 0.0327712
>   C5 0.0333818
>   C6 0.0341960

I did it for a single row. What I don't know, from this point, is how to do it in a loop and paste the subsequent row as new values of this column.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want help you should provide a reproducible example. `?stack` might be useful

Comment: If you're trying to go from wide to long format, use `reshape2::melt`. If you really want just a single column, I think you can just use `rbind` like so: `rbind(df1$col1, df1$col2,..., df1$col6)`

Comment: Never mind on that `rbind` example, it won't work like that.

Comment: `df2 = data.frame(new = unlist(list(df)))`

Comment: Hi Olivia, your approach works for adding the 6 columns together into a single column. However, it does not transform the rows into columns, which is my first issue. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find two solutions :

- this takes a lot of time to be complete

  `new_col <- numeric()`
  `for (i in 1:nrow(xlsx_in))
  {
   message("N rows ", i, " of ", nrow(xlsx_in), " ", i/nrow(xlsx_in), "\n")
   row <- xlsx_in [i, ] 
   col <- as.data.frame(t(row)) 
   new_col <- rbind(new_col, col) 
  }`
- this one is very quick

  `data <-as.vector(t(as.matrix(xlsx_in)))`

  Thank you for your help!